# PyQt: How to connect a QStandardItem in a QStandardItemModel to a function

Tags: python, pyqt, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I am creating an application in PyQt in which I have a a list of check boxes which I have created using QStandardItemModel and QStandardItem and it works perfectly. I want to connect the first item in the list which is a 'Select all' check box to a function. This function should be able to check all the other items of the list. I'm trying to do this by the following code:

```
    model = QStandardItemModel(list)  
    item = QStandardItem("Select all")
    model.appendRow(item)                  
    item.setCheckable(True)
    model.itemChanged.connect(state_changed)

    def state_changed(item):
         print ("Hello")
```

I have added more items to the list from the output of an SQL query and I can see that 'Hello' is printed irrespective of which check box I click. This is my entire code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
def main():  
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC") 
    db.setHostName('LAPTOP-B79DRPA3')
    db.setDatabaseName('local')
    db.open()
    if (db.open()==False):     
      QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error",
                db.lastError().text())   

    query = QSqlQuery () 
    query.exec_  ("select id from [Sarah].[dbo].fraga")

    list = QListView()
    model = QStandardItemModel(list)  

    item = QStandardItem("Select all")
    model.appendRow(item)                  
    item.setCheckable(True)
    model.itemChanged.connect(state_changed)

    while (query.next()):
        item1 = QStandardItem(str(query.value(0)))
        model.appendRow(item1)                  
        item1.setCheckable(True)   

    list.setModel(model)
    list.show()
    return app.exec_()

def state_changed(item):
    print ("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    list = QListView()
    model = QStandardItemModel(list) 
    main()
```

How do I ensure that the function is invoked only when the state of 'Select All' is changed?

Comment: You have connected the `state_changed` function to the `itemChanged` signal of the model. In your own implementation `state_changed` has an item argument. The simplest way is to check if the item argument is the item you need. Right now you are going to have a problem of scope (you did not save your desired item anywhere so it can be tested in another place). I think you should make your implementation inside a class and make your target item a variable of the class (so this becomes possible: `self.item == item`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of connecting to  `QAbstractItemModel.itemChanged` signal, connect to `QAbstractItemView.clicked` signal, which specifies the index clicked. Also, it's advisable not to name a variable `list`, as it interferes with the built-in `list`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
def main():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
    db.setHostName('LAPTOP-B79DRPA3')
    db.setDatabaseName('local')
    db.open()
    if (db.open()==False):
      QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error",
                db.lastError().text())

    query = QSqlQuery ()
    query.exec_  ("select id from [Sarah].[dbo].fraga")

    list_view = QListView()
    model = QStandardItemModel(list_view)

    item = QStandardItem("Select all")
    model.appendRow(item)
    item.setCheckable(True)
    list_view.clicked.connect(state_changed)

    while (query.next()):
        item1 = QStandardItem(str(query.value(0)))
        model.appendRow(item1)
        item1.setCheckable(True)

    list_view.setModel(model)
    list_view.show()
    return app.exec_()

def state_changed(index):
    row = index.row()
    if row == 0:
        print ("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    list_view = QListView()
    model = QStandardItemModel(list)
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @waterboy5281 I have a follow up question. If I want to pass another parameter to the state_changed function, I know I can add by the following way : list_view.clicked.connect(state_changed(newparam)). But now how would I pass the index?

Comment: `list_view.clicked.connect(lambda idx: state_changed(idx, new_param))`. And make sure `state_changed` is modified to accept two arguments